# will_filter gem rails, table width

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'm using will_filter in my rails app. The table I'm using it on has 15 columns, so the table width goes beyond the screen. How to limit this inside a frame and keep a scroll bar below?

Is will_filter advisable to be used? There is very less support for will_filter. There is not even a Stack Overflow tag for this gem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a div wrapping around your table and give that div scroll directive.  Like:

In your view for erb:

```
<div class="scrolly-table">
  <h1> List of all bottles</h1>
  <%= will_filter_table_tag(@bottles) %>
</div>
```

or haml

```
.scrolly-table
  %h1 List of all bottles
  = will_filter_table_tag(@bottles)
```

And In your CSS file

```
.scrolly-table {
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Do you use will_filter? how is it? "Export Data" does not work for me.. why?

Comment: It works well to create a mini admin interface if you're using the actions or tag.  I've used it in rails 3.2.8-13 with ruby 1.9.3 and have no problems with the export, though the json file outputs with a txt extension which is ideal, but everything else works fine.

Comment: Hey.. in will_filter gem.. these 2 divs are loading after 40 seconds... this slows my application load time...<div id="wf_calendar" class="wf_calendar" style="display: none;"></div>
<div id="wf_exporter" class="wf_exporter" style="display: none;"></div>